# I need to get a list of the image elements of a web page

Tags: html, qt, qwebview

I have a `QWebView` in which I load a web page. It it possible to get a list of all images that appear on it? I need to select from the list images that appears on the web page me with a box. Is it possible ?
Thanks in advance.
greetings

EDIT:
Here is what I've tried:

```
void Revision::on_pushButton_6_clicked() 
{ 
  //ui->textEdit->paste(); 
  //ui->textEdit("Hols"); 
  //load(ui->webView->); 
  QString selectedHtml(); 
  QDomAttr imagen; 
  imagen.isElement(); 
  imagen.value(); 
  ui->textEdit->addAction(close()); 
}
```

Comment: `Now I need you to give me a button` -- wrong, that's not how Stack Overflow works.  This isn't a "here, have some code" site, you need to show what you've tried so far, and what didn't work.

Comment: void Revision::on_pushButton_6_clicked()
{
    //ui->textEdit->paste();
    //ui->textEdit("Hols");
    //load(ui->webView->);
    QString selectedHtml();
    QDomAttr imagen;
    imagen.isElement();

    imagen.value();
    ui->textEdit->addAction(close());

}

Comment: I'm trying that when you press the button appears in the list of images textEdit the website

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this to get the image elements:

```
webView.page()->mainFrame()->findAllElements("img");
```

Where the given string is a search pattern in [CSS selector syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) (the one above basically matches all img elements).

Then you can things like extractting the URL of the element and downloading the image or whatever you need.